# How to list files in a directory in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

I am unable to list files in a directory with this code

```
import os
from os import listdir
def fn():       # 1.Get file names from directory
    file_list=os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Jerry\Downloads\prank\prank")
    print (file_list)

 #2.To rename files
     fn()
```

on running the code it gives no output !

Comment: Is your function even being called? From what you've posted, it looks like the call to `fn()` is inside the definition of `fn()`

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @khelwood .. Sir I am new to python ! how do i solve it ?

Comment: @xunatai No not at all!

Comment: unindent the last line of your code, `fn()`

Comment: @Jaskunwarsingh just un-indent the call to `fn()`

Comment: Thank you @nikpod

Comment: @Jaskunwarsingh, you could accept my answer if you found it useful

Comment: yes sir @nikpod

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function call `fn()` was inside the function definition `def fn()`. You must call it outside by unindenting the last line of your code:

```
import os
def fn():       # 1.Get file names from directory
    file_list=os.listdir(r"C:\Users")
    print (file_list)

 #2.To rename files
fn()
```

Comment: Remove the `from os import listdir` line too

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this

```
for file_ in os.listdir(exec_dir):
  if os.path.isdir(exec_dir+file):
        print file_
```

I hope this is useful.

Comment: [edit] your answer, highlight the code, press `ctrl k` .

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to list all files including sub dirs.
you can use this recursive solution**

```
import os
def fn(dir=r"C:\Users\aryan\Downloads\opendatakit"): 
    file_list = os.listdir(dir)
    res = []
    # print(file_list)
    for file in file_list:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, file)):
                res.append(file)
        else:
            result = fn(os.path.join(dir, file))
            if result:
                res.extend(fn(os.path.join(dir, file)))
    return res


res = fn()
print(res)
print(len(res))
```